# Advice is not called from struts 2 action?

Tags: java, spring, struts2, aop, struts2-spring-plugin

Below i have define aspect in aop.xml

```
<aspects>
      <aspect name="com.customer.MyCustomAspect" />
 </aspects>
```

My Custom Aspect is define below

```
    @Aspect
    public class MyCustomAspect{
        @Around("@annotation(requiredPrivilege)")
            public Object myAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

    }
```

Now when i call any service method from struts 2 action, myAdvice is not called. Every thing  works fine with my legacy action but not with struts 2 action
(Just for information i am using struts2 spring plugin jar). I am not what is the issue with struts 2?

Comment: Not enough information to help.

Comment: For Aspects to work, Spring needs to proxy the classes that are advised, does it do this?

Comment: To do what Sotirios explains you'll need to add the struts2-spring-plugin and follow the documentation to use spring for internal Struts2 object creation. Then spring magic will apply to the actions as Spring will be creating them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the struts2-sping-plugin to your project.

Add the following to struts.xml...

```
<constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory" />
```

For more information see:
http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/spring-plugin.html

Since spring is now in charge of object creation it will now be able to perform it's spring AOP magic (assuming spring is configured correctly).